# MSDAX 2012 Onhand Calculation from InventSum & InventTrans tables

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have used the below query to calculate the onhand quantity from InventTrans table but that onhand does not match with the AvailPhysical and/or PhysicalInvent of InventSum table. I have tried matching with other quantities as well but onhand is not matching. Please guide me what am i missing here

```
SELECT T1.ITEMID AS ITEMID
            ,T1.QTY
            ,T1.INVENTDIMID AS INVENTDIMID
            ,DATEDIFF(dd, T3.TRANSDATE, getdate()) AS Age
            ,t19.price as RetailPrice
            ,t1.CurrencyCode AS CurrencyKey
            ,T1.DATAAREAID AS DATAAREAID
            ,T1.PARTITION AS PARTITION
        FROM INVENTTRANS T1
        LEFT JOIN INVENTTRANSORIGIN T2 ON (
                T1.INVENTTRANSORIGIN = T2.RECID
                AND (T1.DATAAREAID = T2.DATAAREAID)
                AND (T1.PARTITION = T2.PARTITION)
                )
        INNER JOIN INVENTTRANSPOSTING T3 ON (
                (
                    (
                        (
                            T1.VOUCHERPHYSICAL = T3.VOUCHER
                            AND (T1.DATAAREAID = T3.DATAAREAID)
                            AND (T1.PARTITION = T3.PARTITION)
                            )
                        )
                    AND (
                        T1.DATEPHYSICAL = T3.TRANSDATE
                        AND (T1.DATAAREAID = T3.DATAAREAID)
                        AND (T1.PARTITION = T3.PARTITION)
                        )
                    )
                AND (
                    T1.INVENTTRANSORIGIN = T3.INVENTTRANSORIGIN
                    AND (T2.DATAAREAID = T3.DATAAREAID)
                    AND (T2.PARTITION = T3.PARTITION)
                    )
                ) and t3.INVENTTRANSPOSTINGTYPE in (0)
        LEFT JOIN INVENTDIM t4 ON (
                t4.inventdimid = t1.inventdimid
                AND t4.PARTITION = t1.PARTITION
                AND t4.dataareaid = t1.dataareaid
                )

                LEFT OUTER JOIN INVENTTABLEMODULE T19 ON T19.ItemID = T1.ItemID AND T19.DataAreaID = T1.DataAreaID and T19.Partition = T1.Partition AND T19.MODULETYPE=0
                LEFT OUTER JOIN INVENTTABLE T20 ON T1.ITEMID = T20.ITEMID AND T1.DATAAREAID = T20.DATAAREAID 
                where T20.ITEMTYPE <> 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try executing this code and capture sql profile and see if it can help you. ItemId itemId;
InventDim inventDimCriteria;
InventDimParm inventDimParm;
InventSumDateDim inventSumDateDim;
;
// Specify the item to get onhand info on
itemId = "1111";
inventDimCriteria.InventColorId = "Red";
inventDimParm.initFromInventDim(inventDimCriteria);
inventSumDateDim =
InventSumDateDim::newParameters(mkdate(31,07,2016),
itemId,
inventDimCriteria,
inventDimParm);

Comment: I don't see how you are trying to get on hand here. It looks like you are just getting the quantities from posted invent transactions. Are you then summing those later or  do you expect for the quantity field in that query to be on hand? Realize that the transaction amounts are only going to be the amount of change for that transaction and not the total amount of inventory.